# legend looks strange for joint line and bar plot in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am trying to draw both a line plot and a bar plot in the same plot.
However, the legend for the line plot looks wrong.

**Question:**
How do I make the legend look like the legend for a regular line plot?

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      ylabel=Inventory,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=47,
      height=4cm,
      width=\textwidth,
      ymin=0,
      xtick={0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44},
      xticklabels={Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun},
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.33)},anchor=north},
      legend columns=4]
    \addplot[sharp plot,black,very thick] coordinates
        {(0, 100) (1, 90) (2,80) (3,70)
         (4,160) (5,150) (6,140) (7,130)
         (8,120) (9,110) (10,100) (12,90)};
    \addplot[bar width=4pt,draw=purple,fill=purple] coordinates
        {(0, 100) (4,0) (8,0) (12,80)};
    \legend{Inventory, Shipments};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add the `line legend` option to that `\addplot` command:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      ylabel=Inventory,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=47,
      height=4cm,
      width=\textwidth,
      ymin=0,
      xtick={0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44},
      xticklabels={Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun},
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.33)},anchor=north},
      legend columns=4]
    \addplot[line legend,sharp plot,black,very thick] coordinates
        {(0, 100) (1, 90) (2,80) (3,70)
         (4,160) (5,150) (6,140) (7,130)
         (8,120) (9,110) (10,100) (12,90)};
    \addplot[bar width=4pt,draw=purple,fill=purple] coordinates
        {(0, 100) (4,0) (8,0) (12,80)};
    \legend{Inventory,Shipments};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

An alternative way to do this would be to remove the `ybar` option from the `axis` options, and write the second `\addplot` as

```
\addplot[ybar,ybar legend,....]{...}
```

See section 4.9.5 of the `pgfplots` manual for more such options.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for letting me know about the options `line legend` and `ybar legend` which are new to me.