# How to make a figure like this with LaTeX pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

It is so hard to make the axis name in two lines. and is it possible to make a figure which has two different y axis?

Time vs Number of publications containing the keywords "A + B"：

```
(2006，752) 
(2007，888)
(2008，908) 
(2009，920) 
(2010，1010) 
(2012，1081) 
(2013，1082) 
(2014，1075) 
(2015，1092) 
(2016，1100) 
(2011，1003) 
(2012，1081) 
(2013，1082) 
(2014，1075) 
(2015，1092) 
(2016，1100)
```

Time vs Number of publications containing the keywords "C + D"：

```
(2006，6) 
(2007，4) 
(2008，4) 
(2009，5) 
(2010，5) 
(2012，9) 
(2013，6) 
(2014，6) 
(2015，2) 
(2016，6) 
(2011，6) 
(2012，11) 
(2013，13) 
(2014，21) 
(2015，22) 
(2016，23)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! No, it is not hard. What is hard is to invent all the data. Please post what you have tried.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) So you are searching for something similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286053/pgfplots-legend-with-two-ordinates-lines-and-bar-chart?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448511/how-to-make-a-figure-like-this-with-latex-pgfplot#comment1126887_448511) creating a graph with two y-axis sharing one x-axis, an example can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286098/95441.

Below I show you two different ways (of many others) on how you can provide multi-line axis labels. The "best" implementation depends on your specific requirements.

(I don't provide a *full* solution answering *all* your question in one answer here, because I don't see the point showing the "the same thing" one time as a bar-chart and one time as a line. I recommend showing Either both of them as bars or both of them as lines.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={This is a very long axis label spanning over two lines},
        xlabel style={
            text width=10em,
        },
        ylabel={This is a very long axis label \\ spanning over two lines},
        ylabel style={
            align=center,
        },
    ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Since you asked several [follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) already were the "problem" of multi-line axis labels were solved, it would be nice if you could consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) this answer (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓) if it helped you.