# How to draw a little arrow on the data bar?

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

Here is a MWE. It does not quite produce my desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\footnotesize
\pgfplotsset{
   width=0.45\textwidth,
   height=0.3\textheight,
   symbolic x coords={2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017},
   enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.05},
   }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xtick pos=left,
   axis y line*=left,
   ybar,
   bar width=0.2cm,
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
   ytick={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
   yticklabels={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
   ylabel style={align=center},
   ylabel={Number of publication containing the keywords \\ ``A+B'},
   xtick=data,
   xticklabel style={
      inner sep=0pt,
      anchor=north east,
      rotate=60
      }
   ]
   \addplot[ybar legend,fill=gray,draw=gray] coordinates {
     (2006,1) (2007,8) (2008,6) (2009,7) (2010,11) (2011,9) (2012,30) (2013,25) (2014,18) (2015,37) (2016,46) (2017,0)
     };
     \end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
   axis y line*=right,
   xticklabels={},
   ymin=700, ymax=1200,
   ytick={700,800,900,1000,1100,1200},
   ylabel style={align=center,rotate=180,red},
   ylabel={Number of publication containing the keywords \\ ``C+D''},
   ]
    \addplot[thick,draw=red] plot coordinates{
      (2006,752) (2007,888) (2008,908) (2009,920) (2010,1010) (2011,1003) (2012,1081) (2013,1082) (2014,1075) (2015,1092) (2016,1100) (2017,0)
      };
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Evolution of the number of publications in indexed journals containing the keywords ``A+B'' and ``C+D'' between 2006 and 2016.}
\label{tongji}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the record: This is (another) [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/95441) of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448511/how-to-make-a-figure-like-this-with-latex-pgfplot

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this arrow?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
%    width=0.45\textwidth,
%    height=0.3\textheight,
   symbolic x coords={2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017},
   enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.05},
   }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xtick pos=left,
   axis y line*=left,
   ybar,
   bar width=0.2cm,
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
   ytick={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
   yticklabels={0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
   ylabel style={align=center},
   ylabel={Number of publication containing the keywords \\ ``A+B'},
   xtick=data,
   xticklabel style={
      inner sep=0pt,
      anchor=north east,
      rotate=60
      }
   ]
   \addplot[ybar legend,fill=gray,draw=gray] coordinates {
     (2006,1) (2007,8) (2008,6) (2009,7) (2010,11) (2011,9) (2012,30) (2013,25) (2014,18) (2015,37) (2016,46) (2017,0)
     };
     \end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
   axis y line*=right,
   xticklabels={},
   ymin=700, ymax=1200,
   ytick={700,800,900,1000,1100,1200},
   ylabel style={align=center,rotate=180,red},
   ylabel={Number of publication containing the keywords \\ ``C+D''},
   ]
    \addplot[thick,draw=red] plot coordinates{
      (2006,752) (2007,888) (2008,908) (2009,920) (2010,1010) (2011,1003) (2012,1081) (2013,1082) (2014,1075) (2015,1092) (2016,1100) (2017,0)
      };
      \coordinate (X) at (axis cs:2013,1082);     
   \end{axis}
   \draw[thick,red,-latex] (X) |- ++(0.5,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LiamChang If that worked for you, could you please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark left of it? Likewise, please consider accepting answers to previous questions. BTW, the downvote of your recent question is not from me, but you would help yourself and others by adding the code.